# What are all of Batman's combat moves in Batman: Arkham Asylum?

Tags: achievements, batman-arkham-asylum

The *Freeflow Perfection* trophy/achievement in *Batman: Arkham Asylum* requires you to use all of Batman's combat moves in one freeflow combination.  What are all these moves?  What controller buttons are used to make them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The moves you have to perform in a single combo are (PS3 / 360 / PC):

- Strike (<kbd>Square</kbd> / <kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>Mouse Left</kbd>)
- Counter (<kbd>Triangle</kbd> / <kbd>Y</kbd> / <kbd>Mouse Right</kbd>)
- Cape Stun (<kbd>Circle</kbd> / <kbd>B</kbd> / <kbd>Mouse Middle</kbd>)
- Evade (<kbd>X</kbd> x2 / <kbd>A</kbd> x2 / <kbd>Space</kbd> x2)
- Throw (<kbd>Square</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Left</kbd>)
- Takedown (<kbd>Triangle</kbd> + <kbd>Circle</kbd> / <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Right</kbd>)
- Ground Takedown (<kbd>R2</kbd> + <kbd>Triangle</kbd> / <kbd>RT</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl Left</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Right</kbd>)
- Batarang (<kbd>L1</kbd> / <kbd>LT</kbd> / <kbd>Q</kbd>)
- Batclaw (<kbd>R2</kbd> x2 / <kbd>RT</kbd> x2 / <kbd>C</kbd>)

As far as which order and where to do it, I would check sites like [True Achievements](http://www.trueachievements.com/a35488/freeflow-perfection-achievement.htm) (Xbox 360), or [PS3 Trophies Forums](http://www.ps3trophies.com/forums/batman-arkham-asylum/9047-easy-freeflow-perfection.html) for some tips. Check [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=freeflow+perfection&aq=f) as well, there's loads of videos for it and a bunch of different possible solutions.

Comment: See also http://www.allgame.com/game.php?id=66506&tab=controls for a list of control keys.